# Hibernate one to many unidirectional relation using multiple columns of sql type CHAR

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entities named "Padre" and "Figlio"
Padre is the owner, Figlio is the child
Padre's primary key has two columns, PADREK1 and PADREK2, both CHAR(20)
Figlio's primary key has four columns:
PADREPADREK1 (foreign) CHAR(20)
PADREPADREK2 (foreign) CHAR(20)
FIGLIOK1 CHAR(20)
FIGLIOK2 CHAR(20)

This is the code of my entity class

```
    public class PadreBean extends BaseEntityBean3 implements Serializable
    {
       @EmbeddedId
       PadrePK iPadrePK;
       @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
       private String iDescription;
       @Column(name = "ABSUNIQUEID")
       private long iABSUniqueId;
       @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinColumns(
          {
             @JoinColumn(name = "ABSOUTQUEUENAME", nullable = true)
          })
       private ABSOutQueueBean iAbsOutQueueBean;
       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "PADREPADREK1", referencedColumnName = "PADREK1"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "PADREPADREK2", referencedColumnName = "PADREK2")
       })
       List iFiglioBeans;
       ......
```

iFiglioBeans is the collection of children

The problem is:
If both Padre's primary key columns are filled using all 20 characters, all works well;
id padre's primary key columns are not totally filled Hibernate does loads the collection
but after loading it clears its content.

I have activated the Hibernate logging and, when my code access the children collection I see:

```
    [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Obtaining JDBC connection
    [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Obtained JDBC connection
    [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Result set contains (possibly empty) collection: [com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans#component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1, iPadreK1=p1}]
    [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Result set row: 0
    [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Result row: EntityKey[com.dat.abs.run.FiglioBean#component[iFiglioK1,iFiglioK2,iPadrePadreK1,iPadrePadreK2]{iFiglioK2=1                   , iPadrePadreK1=p1                  , iFiglioK1=1                   , iPadrePadreK2=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Found row of collection: [com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans#component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1                  , iPadreK1=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Result set row: 1
    [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Result row: EntityKey[com.dat.abs.run.FiglioBean#component[iFiglioK1,iFiglioK2,iPadrePadreK1,iPadrePadreK2]{iFiglioK2=f1                  , iPadrePadreK1=p1                  , iFiglioK1=f1                  , iPadrePadreK2=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Found row of collection: [com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans#component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1                  , iPadreK1=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Resolving associations for [com.dat.abs.run.FiglioBean#component[iFiglioK1,iFiglioK2,iPadrePadreK1,iPadrePadreK2]{iFiglioK2=1                   , iPadrePadreK1=p1                  , iFiglioK1=1                   , iPadrePadreK2=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Done materializing entity [com.dat.abs.run.FiglioBean#component[iFiglioK1,iFiglioK2,iPadrePadreK1,iPadrePadreK2]{iFiglioK2=1                   , iPadrePadreK1=p1                  , iFiglioK1=1                   , iPadrePadreK2=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Resolving associations for [com.dat.abs.run.FiglioBean#component[iFiglioK1,iFiglioK2,iPadrePadreK1,iPadrePadreK2]{iFiglioK2=f1                  , iPadrePadreK1=p1                  , iFiglioK1=f1                  , iPadrePadreK2=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Done materializing entity [com.dat.abs.run.FiglioBean#component[iFiglioK1,iFiglioK2,iPadrePadreK1,iPadrePadreK2]{iFiglioK2=f1                  , iPadrePadreK1=p1                  , iFiglioK1=f1                  , iPadrePadreK2=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) 2 collections were found in result set for role: com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans
    [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Collection fully initialized: [com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans#component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1, iPadreK1=p1}]
    [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Collection fully initialized: [com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans#component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1                  , iPadreK1=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) 2 collections initialized for role: com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans
    [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Releasing JDBC connection
    [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Released JDBC connection
    [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Done loading collection
    [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Processing flush-time cascades
    
    [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Dirty checking collections
    [org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Collection found: [com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans#component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1, iPadreK1=p1}], was: [com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans#component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1, iPadreK1=p1}] (initialized)
    [org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Found collection with unloaded owner: [com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean.iFiglioBeans#component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1                  , iPadreK1=p1                  }]
    [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 4 objects
    [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 2 collections
    [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Listing entities:
    [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) com.dat.abs.run.FiglioBean{iDescrizioneFiglio=                    , iFiglioPK=component[iFiglioK1,iFiglioK2,iPadrePadreK1,iPadrePadreK2]{iFiglioK2=1                   , iPadrePadreK1=p1                  , iFiglioK1=1                   , iPadrePadreK2=p1                  }, iABSUniqueId=249}
    [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) com.dat.abs.run.ABSOutQueueBean{iCreationDateTime=2012-02-17 07:51:10.0, iLastUpdateUser=null, iCreationUser=system                   , iLastUpdateDateTime=null, iPrintServiceName=null, iId=component[iName]{iName=#01                 }, iDescription=01                                                }
    [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) com.dat.abs.run.FiglioBean{iDescrizioneFiglio=f1                  , iFiglioPK=component[iFiglioK1,iFiglioK2,iPadrePadreK1,iPadrePadreK2]{iFiglioK2=f1                  , iPadrePadreK1=p1                  , iFiglioK1=f1                  , iPadrePadreK2=p1                  }, iABSUniqueId=248}
    [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) com.dat.abs.run.PadreBean{iPadrePK=component[iPadreK1,iPadreK2]{iPadreK2=p1, iPadreK1=p1}, iAbsOutQueueBean=com.dat.abs.run.ABSOutQueueBean#component[iName]{iName=#01                 }, iDescription=p1                  , iABSUniqueId=247, iFiglioBeans=[]}
    [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Releasing JDBC connection
    [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Aggressively releasing JDBC connection
```

As you see Hibernate first loads the children, but after cleans it.
See in log attached before the line with:  **Found collection with unloaded owner:**  message

The problem is the white space that DBMs uses to fill the CHARs column, has I've already said, if I insert all characters in my keys columns all works as well.

So, is there a solution to have my children collection by Hibernate using the CHAR columns as primary keys not completely filled?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem writing a my own user type.
I post here because might be useful for other.
Test both using db2 9.x and Oracle 12c

```
    package com.dat.abs.run;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Types;

    import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
    import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
    import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

    public class ABSChar implements UserType
    {
       public int[] sqlTypes()
       {
          return new int[]
             {
                Types.CHAR,
             };
       }
       public Class returnedClass()
       {
          return String.class;
       }
       public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException
       {
          return (x == y) || (x != null && y != null && (x.equals(y)));
       }
       public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException
       {
          if (value == null)
             return null;
          return new String((String) value);
       }
       public boolean isMutable()
       {
          return false;
       }
       @Override
       public int hashCode(Object aValue) throws HibernateException
       {
          return aValue.hashCode();
       }
       @Override
       public Object replace(Object aOriginal, Object aTarget, Object aOwner) throws HibernateException
       {
          return aOriginal;
       }
       @Override
       public Object assemble(Serializable aChaced, Object aOwner) throws HibernateException
       {
          return aChaced;
       }
       @Override
       public Serializable disassemble(Object aValue) throws HibernateException
       {
          return (Serializable) aValue;
       }
       @Override
       public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet aRs, String[] aNames, SessionImplementor aSession, Object aOwner) throws HibernateException, SQLException
       {
          String val = aRs.getString(aNames[0]);
          if (val == null)
          {
             return null;
          }
          return val.trim();
       }
       @Override
       public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement aStatament, Object aValue, int aIndex, SessionImplementor aSession) throws HibernateException, SQLException
       {
          aStatament.setString(aIndex, (String) aValue);
       }
    }
```

And this to use the type in bean class

```
       @Type(type = "com.dat.abs.run.ABSChar")
       @Column(name = "PADREPADREK1", length = 20)
       private String iPadrePadreK1;
       @Type(type = "com.dat.abs.run.ABSChar")
       @Column(name = "PADREPADREK2", length = 20)
       private String iPadrePadreK2;
       @Type(type = "com.dat.abs.run.ABSChar")
       @Column(name = "FIGLIOK1", length = 20)
       private String iFiglioK1;
       @Type(type = "com.dat.abs.run.ABSChar")
       @Column(name = "FIGLIOK2", length = 20)
```